# Deep learning with $p \gg N$ and on multi-modal and heterogeneous data

Tags: classification, dimensionality-reduction, deep-learning

I work in a problem where:

- The input data is a collection of time series from different sensor
  modalities, where each sensor comes with different acquisition rates
  and dynamic ranges
- The number of potential features vastly exceeds the number of
  instances (i.e. $p \gg N$)

My question is: **Has deep learning been applied on this type of data before?**

Comment: I have seen random forests of gradient boosted trees applied to dimensionality reduction for that type of data.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a very related question ([Successful applications of deep learning apart from image classification and NLP](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/126296/61120)) more than two weeks ago and got no answer. My own search turned up only very few deep learning approaches apart from image analysis and natural language processing. Hence, I am quite sure that the answer to your question is: no, deep learning hasn't been applied to such a problem up to now. Go ahead and be the first one ☺

Comment: I posted a question recently on application of deep learning to combinatorial optimization: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225636/is-deep-learning-useful-for-combinatorial-optimization/229697#229697 . Got one interesting answer.