# Successful applications of deep learning apart from image classification and NLP

Tags: deep-learning, application

Are there any successful applications of deep learning apart from image classification and NLP? I am aware of the [winning approach](http://blog.kaggle.com/2012/11/01/deep-learning-how-i-did-it-merck-1st-place-interview/) of the Merck challenge on Kaggle only. However, I could not find more details on their approach. I am interested in a wider application of deep learning - preferably with open source code or at least a published paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out there aren't much other applications of deep learning. However, [Leung et al](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/12/i121.short) use a deep learning approach in life science. [technobabble] They predict alternative splicing in different mouse tissues based on RNA-Seq data [/technobabble]. The authors provide no source code but at least some details about their implementation - which is good enough for me (and maybe other readers here, too).

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf) paper uses deep learning to play Atari games, which is a reinforcement learning problem. The neural nets are used to learn the action-value function $Q(s,a)$ of a state $s$ and an action $a$.

Comment: `input is raw pixels and whose output is a value function estimating future rewards` Hm, this is quite close to image classification - but thanks anyway :)