# Is deep learning useful for combinatorial optimization?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning

Are there research groups working on using deep learning for combinatorial optimization problems?

Answer (score 14):

Yep, there's a paper [Pointer Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03134v1.pdf) that tries to use deep learning to solve convex hull, Delaunay triangulation and TSP, the result looks promising, or at least it can be used as a good starting point for optimization algorithms.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Machine learning** can be used in the branch and bound algorithm to

- Select a branching variable (Khalil, Elias Boutros, et al. "Learning to branch in mixed integer programming." *Thirtieth AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence.* 2016.)
- Decide whether or not to run a primal heuristic at a node (Khalil, Elias B., et al. "Learning to Run Heuristics in Tree Search." *IJCAI.* 2017.)

**Reinforcement learning** can be used to

- Learn a better criterion for greedy solution construction over a graph distribution (Khalil, Elias, et al. "Learning combinatorial optimization algorithms over graphs." *Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems.* 2017.)

Check Bistra Dilkina's (who seems to pioneered this approach) [talk](https://bluejeans.com/s/73i6n/) at USC ISI [AI seminar](https://www.isi.edu/technology_groups/insy/events/machine_learning_helps_discrete_optimization).